# how to select distinct rows from two tables linked with foreign key

Tags: mysql

I want to show images from database.I have two tables 
gallery_photos[image]

gallery_category
[image]

I want to show any photos_filename with category_name.  photo_category is the foreign key of category_id

mysql query i wrote

```
SELECT distinct a.category_name
       ,b.photo_filename 
FROM gallery_category a  
inner join gallery_photos b  on (a.category_id=b.photo_category)
```

please help me to do that...

i want to select exactly like this

```
albums/1456226111.jpg interior
albums/1456226239.jpg graphics
albums/1456226339.jpg random
albums/1456226478.jpg goods
```

Comment: albums/1456226122.jpg 
albums/1456226153.jpg 
albums/1456226168.jpg this images belogs from interior category. so why you write in graphics, random and goods ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can grouping it by group by

```
SELECT a.category_name,b.photo_filename 
FROM gallery_category a  JOIN gallery_photos b  
ON a.category_id=b.photo_category 
GROUP BY a.category_name
```

Comment: @SibyXavier its my pleasure.

Comment: you sure it's working? b.photo_filename Column is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 1):

Use Left join to keep all the rows in the left table.

```
SELECT 
  b.photo_filename, 
  a.category_name 
FROM 
  gallery_category a  LEFT join gallery_photos b  ON (a.category_id=b.photo_category)
```

check this out!

[What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)

Comment: its show all image from all category but he want only one image per category am i right ? @SibyXavier

Comment: but what if there is more than one image in the category?what is the criteria to pick ?